# Trying to save value in local storage

Tags: javascript, onclick, local-storage

```
 function mySystem() { 
const prefersDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');toggleDarkTheme(prefersDark.matches);prefersDark.addListener((mediaQuery) => toggleDarkTheme(mediaQuery.matches));function toggleDarkTheme(shouldAdd) { document.body.classList.toggle('drK', shouldAdd);}}
```

Want to use local.storage i tried a lot but idid not getting how to use local.storage here.

Comment: I'm not sure about your requirement. But I believe you need to use `localStorage.setItem("key", "value")` to store values in a local storage. Take a look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for more fore detail. Let me know if it helps  you

Comment: its system default function that works onclick i want to make it when users click one time then when again they visit that want to stay in that mode